# Mac The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jarsigner

Tags: java, jarsigner

My purpose is to use jarsigner to sign apk.

I get the following prompt：

```
% jarsigner     
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jarsigner.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

my java version hint：

```
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)
```

Mac version is 11.6.3

How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: I use (and recommend) [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) to manage my Java environments.

Comment: I think you installed jre instead of jdk

Comment: Or the environment variables are incorrectly configured. The jarsigner is in JAVA_HOME/bin.

Comment: my jarsigner location is here `% whereis jarsigner /usr/bin/jarsigner`

Comment: How to determine if jdk is installed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally solved it by downloading the [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

Comment: I used this link to avoid having to create an account with oracle but this worked for me too. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-mac

Comment: Do I need to do something more to make it work? I have installed it but it doesn't work? Should I deactivate the virtual environment? Thanks

Answer (score 65):

Mac users, follow the below steps:

1. ```bash
   brew install openjdk@11
   ```
2. For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with:

   ```bash
   sudo ln -sfn $(brew --prefix)/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
   ```

Reference: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk@11

This approach will also work for other versions.

Comment: You shouldn't need to symlink. Most programs respect `JAVA_HOME` env-var

Comment: It's an alternate way to point Java to correct JDK. For me, first time setup with brew required me to execute symlink. Second scenario, in case you have multiple Java JDK, symlink to switch to correct JDK also works.

Comment: symlink command needed in MacOS

Answer (score 2):

You need to check jdk version which installed to our system.
This example is for mac os with m1.

Enter in your terminal:

```
java -version
```

Output:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_372"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.70.0.23-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_372-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.70.0.23-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.372-b07, mixed mode)
```

Then input the commands:

1. `sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`
2. echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   or ~/.bashrc
3. export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include"

It worked for me

Comment: I did the same thing ans still I have same error

Comment: This actually worked, and now Xcode is happy to build the Kotlin Multiplatform project.